# Reading a file, line by line and then read that line word by word in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, c++17, c++14

I am trying to read through a text file line by line and then I am trying to read that line word by word. Once I found a particular word, skip the remaining word from that line and jump to next line.
I tried this way:

```
    void SymbolScanning::symScanning()
    {
        std::string s;
        std::ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open("SymbolRead.txt");
        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
           while(std::getline(myfile, s))
           {
              std::istringstream iss(s);
              std::string word;
              while(iss >> word)
              {
                  std::cout << word << std::endl;
                 // if desired word found, skip remainnig word and jump
                 // over next line.
              }
           }
       }
       else
          cout<<"File is not open";
    }
```

Output : File is not open.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by its not working. what kind of input did you give it?

Comment: `// if desired word found, skip remainnig word and jump`   `// over next line.` -- Comments are ignored by the compiler.  Of course nothing will be done.  You haven't posted any executable code that actually does something.

Comment: @Borgleader I gave input as SymbolRead.txt file. But it does not enter in while loop.

Comment: @tushar -- You failed to check if the file was successfully opened.  Then `std::cout << sub << std::endl;` -- What is `sub`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have updated the code.  Please look into it.

Comment: @tushar The code is not a [mcve].  You are calling this code within a class, and we have no idea when, where, or how the instance of `SymbolScanning` is being used.  We also don't know anything about the file being used.

Comment: Also, if the output is `File is not open`, then the problem has absolutely nothing to do with outputting words.  It has everything to do with that file not being able to be opened.  Maybe specify a full path instead of just the name?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is working. I changed name with full path and it is working. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  One more doubt. In file there is a line  `line (60 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE, 106 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE);`  So here words are getting printed as `line`, `(60` , `*` ...... `SCALE);`   Why `(`  and `)` is not consider as a single word ?

Comment: Please open another question, as you are now asking a different question concerning whitespace.